# Convert database column value to array during query buildler laravel and use wherein

Tags: php, laravel

```
 $to_email=Permission::where('price_list',$request->input('price_list')) 
->where('level_one','1')
->whereIn($request ->input('customer_id'),array('permissions.customer_id'))
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'permissions.user_id')
->select('users.fname','users.lname','users.email')
->first();
```

I am trying to use whereIn whereby the database column contains imploded data ie (1,2,3) like data which is customer_id like shown in below image[image]

how can i use WhereIn or query like if customer ID is 2 then select where 2 is in customer_id and return onlly data where 2 exist in customer_id

Comment: You should take a look at normalizing your data. Storing a CSV of ids in `customer_id` is not a good idea, as you're finding out now. A proper many-to-many, using a `pivot` table between `permissions` and `customers`, like `customer_permission`, with `permission_id` and `customer_id` will simplfy this greatly, both in terms of performance (don't need to rely on `LIKE` queries) and data integrity (what would happen now if you deleted Customer 1 or 2?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$request->input('customer_id')` is an integer, and column `customer_id` is `string`, add to query:

```
->where('customer_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->input('customer_id').'%')
```

instead of

```
->whereIn($request->input('customer_id'),array('permissions.customer_id'))
```

Edit: this solution would get all records with id 12, 20, 200 ...(every number that cointains 2).

To prevent this, you could add , (comma) to beginning and end of `customer_id` before storing it to database (your first row's `customer_id` would be `",1,2,"`). Then you could add to query:

```
->where('customer_id', 'LIKE', '%,'.$request->input('customer_id').',%')`
//added comma next to % sign
```

Best practice solution would probably be to use many to many relationship, more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Nice answer, and excellent point on highlighting the issue with `%1%` matching `1, 10, 100, ...`  Definitely illustrates the reason why normalized data is preferred over CSVs of multiple IDs

Comment: Thank you guy i got the solution now the comma separate did the magic initially when i fetch id 1 it would give me both 1,11, like  @Tim and fraB thanks